# Discord.js - How do you use guildUpdate from the client class?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I’m setting up logging for my Discord bot and I don’t know how to use guildUpdate from the client class. The docs say to use the oldGuild and newGuild parameters, but how do you actually check what is being changed (like the server name, region, etc) and display that change? Here’s an example from another bot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYr2W.jpg

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, there is no built in function to compare the two guild objects, so you would have manually look for the differences in the different parameters. For example:

```js
client.on("guildUpdate", (oldGuild, newGuild) => {
    if (oldGuild.description !== newGuild.description) {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("changes")
          .setDescription(`Description changed from ${oldGuild.description} to ${newGuild.description}`)
        somechannel.send(embed)
    }
});
```

Comment: It was no problem!

Answer (score 0):

`guildUpdate` gives you 2 parameters. One is the guild before it was updated, and one is the guild after it was updated.

To see which value has been updated, you can check if the new value equals the old value. If it doesn't, it has been updated.

```js
client.on("guildUpdate", (oldGuild, newGuild) => {
    if (oldGuild.name !== newGuild.name) console.log(`The guild name has been updated. From ${oldGuild.name} to ${newGuild.name}`);
    if (oldGuild.region !== newGuild.region) console.log(`The region has been updated. From ${oldGuild.region} to ${newGuild.region}`);
    // etc
});
```